# Tag manager e-commerce data layer

Tags: wordpress, plugins, google-tag-manager

Im using the google tag manager plugin for wordpress called: "DuracellTomi's Google Tag Manager". I enabled the e-commerce option on it. When i place a test order im forwarded to a custom thank you page. on that thank you page i enter the javascript console mode  and there i type in "dataLayer" and this is the

output:

[image]

I expected something like this:

```
transactionId': '1234',
   'transactionAffiliation': 'Acme Clothing',
   'transactionTotal': 38.26,
   'transactionTax': 1.29,
   'transactionShipping': 5,
   'transactionProducts': [{
       'sku': 'DD44',
       'name': 'T-Shirt',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'price': 11.99,
       'quantity': 1
   },{
       'sku': 'AA1243544',
       'name': 'Socks',
       'category': 'Apparel',
       'price': 9.99,
       'quantity': 2
```

what do i need to do to get the desired output?\

Edit:

My custom thank you page is set up like this:

```
// Redirect custom thank you

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom');

function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $url = 'http://dexport.nl/bedankt';

    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself.

The plugin doesnt asign the datalayer to the custom thank you page.

So there are 2 options.

1. You dont use a custom thank you page and use the default one. once you have done this you can go to your js console in developers tool and type in "data layer" you will get the desired result.
2. You use this plugin for a custom thank you page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-custom-thank-you/